# Using intermediate timesteps in Hamiltonian Monte Carlo

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo

Hamiltonian Monte Carlo methods are usually built on a symplectic time-reversible ODE integrator such as the Leapfrog method. A HMC iteration uses the following sequence of steps:

1. Sample new momenta
2. Run the ODE integrator for $N$ iterations
3. Randomly accept or reject the last state of the ODE integrator based on the change in the Hamiltonian.
4. Do something with the current sample, e.g. compute an expected value.

Steps 2/3 seem very wasteful to me, since dynamics are simulated for $N$ steps, yet only the last step contributes to the output. I wonder if something can be said about intermediate timesteps when it turns out that the trajectory was accepted. Could they also be used as samples from the target distribution? Is there any literature on methods that use the locations of intermediate leapfrog steps?

Comment: I don't know the full answer to your question, but at a first glance it seems like the intermediate lepfrog steps will be highly correlated (not only with each other, but also with the starting and ending point of ODE simulation). This means that using those points to estimate integrals might not give much of an improvement of the estimate ... but I might be wrong (just giving an intuition).

Comment: If it's possible to use intermediate steps as "free" samples (i.e. no involved computational costs) from the target distribution, then I don't see how it could hurt (even if there is strong correlation).